# Samba share redirection after already mapped by 300 computers in the network

Tags: linux, redirect, share, samba

I have created a samba share with a typo in the name. The problem is this share has already been mapped on over 300 computers on the network, and correcting it would lead to remapping all those computers all over again.

So I'm basically thinking if there's any way to redirect a share to another. For example, to redirect users accessing \192.168.0.173\instrutions to \192.168.0.173\instructions (notice the typo?), while also keep the correct share hidden from view.

Answer (score 2):

I found a possible solution [here](http://lzeit.blogspot.se/2010/07/redirecting-samba-share-to-another.html):

```
[global]
host msdfs = true

[work]
msdfs root = true
msdfs proxy = \newserver\work
```

You didn't even try to search on google, did you? This was the first hit on google when searching for 'samba redirect'

Comment: I did and I tried that. I need to redirect to a share on the same server, not a different server...

Comment: so just change `newserver` to `sameserver`?